# Java .class files outside of WEB-INF?

Tags: java, war

I'm reading through the Java EE 7 Tutorial, and I came to the section [Packaging Web Archives](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/packaging003.htm). I'm already familiar with the way Java web applications and WARs should be structured, but something caught my eye:

> A web module has a specific structure. The top-level directory of a web module is the document root of the application. The document root is where XHTML pages, **client-side classes** and archives, and static web resources, such as images, are stored.

What on earth do they mean by "client-side classes"? If you put a `.class` file outside of `WEB-INF`, obviously you can download it using a web browser or other HTTP client. I suppose you could distribute a small application this way. Would these "client-side classes" have any other use?

Comment: Applets, Java Web Start, etc.

Comment: I am familiar with those, but it never occurred to me that you could distribute individual .class files.

Comment: Yes you can. Example: Your web application have a HTML page which embeds an Applet (say, like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html)). The class file (or jar file) for the Applet must be available on the web, so your class (or jar file) should be put outside of the `WEB-INF` package.

Answer (score 4):

I believe what the author is getting at is classes which will be executed on the client-side, such as the browser.

Comment: Do you mean _in_ the browser, like in an Applet?